# Sum last n rows of df.count() results into one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to generate nice summary statistics of a dataframe. Consider the following example:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({"category":['u','v','w','u','y','z','y','z','x','x','y','z','x','z','x']})

>> df['category'].value_counts()
z    4
x    4
y    3
u    2
v    1
w    1

>> ??
           count  pct
z              4  27%
x              4  27%
y              3  20%
Other (3)      4  27%
```

The result sums the value counts of the n=3 last rows up, deletes them and then adds them as one row to the original value counts. Also it would be nice to have everything as percents. Any ideas how to implement this? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DataFrame with percentages use [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with indexing, crate DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), add new row and new column filled by percentages:

```
s = df['category'].value_counts()

n= 3
out = s.iloc[:-n].to_frame('count')
out.loc['Other ({n})'] = s.iloc[-n:].sum()
out['pct'] = out['count'].div(out['count'].sum()).apply(lambda x: f"{x:.0%}")
print (out)
           count  pct
z              4  27%
x              4  27%
y              3  20%
Other (3)      4  27%
```

Comment: I would pass `normalized=True` to `value_counts`, rest is (almost) the same.

Comment: I recommend `out.loc[f"Other ({n})"]` instead of `out.loc['Other (3)']`

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`tail(-3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html) to get the last values except for the first 3:

```
counts = df['category'].value_counts()
others = counts.tail(-3)

counts[f'Others ({len(others)})'] = others.sum()
counts.drop(others.index, inplace=True)

counts.to_frame(name='count').assign(pct=lambda d: d['count'].div(d['count'].sum()).mul(100).round())
```

Output:

```
            count   pct
z               4  27.0
x               4  27.0
y               3  20.0
Others (3)      4  27.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This snippet

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"category":['u','v','w','u','y','z','y','z','x','x','y','z','x','z','x']})
cutoff_index = 3
categegory_counts = pd.DataFrame([df['category'].value_counts(),df['category'].value_counts(normalize=True)],index=["Count","Percent"]).T.reset_index()
other_rows = categegory_counts[cutoff_index:].set_index("index")
categegory_counts = categegory_counts[:cutoff_index].set_index("index")
summary_table = pd.concat([categegory_counts,pd.DataFrame(other_rows.sum(),columns=[f"Other ({len(other_rows)})"]).T])
summary_table = summary_table.astype({'Count':'int'})
summary_table['Percent'] = summary_table['Percent'].apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x*100))
print(summary_table)
```

will give you what you need. Also in a nice format;)

```
           Count Percent
z              4  26.67%
x              4  26.67%
y              3  20.00%
Other (3)      4  26.67%
```